# How can I populate a table when inner join values might be null?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm populating a table which is fetching the ids from 2 other tables to display their information, for example, delivery has a Hamburguer and the box, but the user might register the delivery with out the box, only with the hamburguer.

When I make a `INNER JOIN` `SELECT` to get the data from the `DB` it will return 0 results since there is no box and I'm trying to compare the ids that don't exist. It doesn't populate the table then.

```
SELECT
  entrega_telemovel.*,
  telemovel.id_telemovel,
  telemovel.nroserie,
  nro_telemovel.numero_telemovel,
  nro_telemovel.id_nrotelemovel,
  funcionarios.id_funcionario,
  funcionarios.nome
FROM entrega_telemovel
INNER JOIN telemovel
  ON entrega_telemovel.telemovel = telemovel.id_telemovel
INNER JOIN nro_telemovel
  ON nro_telemovel.id_nrotelemovel = entrega_telemovel.numero_telemovel
INNER JOIN funcionarios
  ON funcionarios.id_funcionario = entrega_telemovel.funcionario_entrega 
ORDER BY funcionarios.nome;
```

In this query above `entrega_telemovel.telemovel=telemovel.id_telemovel` the value in `entrega_telemovel.telemovel` is null like the example I gave above. So 0 results are returned from the query.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN and a GROUP BY.

Comment: @colburton left join will show me the matches to ?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh added my PHP page where the table is

Comment: Do you think it's a PHP problem or SQL problem?

Comment: Amazing, who gave me a downvote on the question ? i couldent find a solution in any other place. Just wow.

Comment: Why did you post the PHP code? You are just making your question less clear.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel jarlh asked for some sample data table, so i added it.

Comment: That is not sample data.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i tought he asked for some table code sample. My bad then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a LEFT JOIN.
INNER JOIN only combines rows, that exist in both tables. A LEFT JOIN on the other hand always produces at least one row. If on table does not have a match for it, all columns are set to NULL.

```
SELECT
  entrega_telemovel.*,
  telemovel.id_telemovel,
  telemovel.nroserie,
  nro_telemovel.numero_telemovel,
  nro_telemovel.id_nrotelemovel,
  funcionarios.id_funcionario,
  funcionarios.nome
FROM entrega_telemovel
LEFT JOIN telemovel
  ON entrega_telemovel.telemovel = telemovel.id_telemovel
LEFT JOIN nro_telemovel
  ON nro_telemovel.id_nrotelemovel = entrega_telemovel.numero_telemovel
LEFT JOIN funcionarios
  ON funcionarios.id_funcionario = entrega_telemovel.funcionario_entrega
ORDER BY funcionarios.nome;
```

Comment: It did work, thanks coulburton, since i only know inner joins i was in panic, will have to study left joins to understand. Solved, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show all `entrega_telemovel` entries, no matter whether they have a match in `entrega_telemovel` or not. This is what an outer join does.

```
SELECT ...
FROM entrega_telemovel et
LEFT OUTER JOIN telemovel t ON et.telemovel = t.id_telemovel
...
```